# How to filter objects by number of ForeignKey objects WITHOUT using raw SQL?

Tags: python, django, orm, django-aggregation

Is this finally possible in Django? Without this feature, using ORM is kinda strange.

Comment: Search is a good place to start.  I think this has been asked more than once.

Comment: And every answer (that i saw) involve raw SQL.

Comment: naturally after I answered... near duplicate  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889176/filtering-the-aggregate-in-the-django-orm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually two sections in the Django aggregation docs called [filtering on annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations) and [`order_by()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#order-by) that should get you what you need:

```
books_w_author_count = Book.objects.annotate(num_authors=Count('authors'))

# just a filter by number of objects
books_w_author_count.filter(num_authors__gt=1)

# just ordering on the count
books_w_author_count.order_by('num_authors')

class Author(modules.Model):
   # ...

class Book(models.Model):
   # ...
   authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can this by using anotate function. [**Here**](http://twigstechtips.blogspot.com/2011/05/django-filter-by-aggregate-count-using.html) you can find an example

And docs [**here**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses)